# Inserting data into database returns MismatchedInputException error

Tags: serialization, kotlin, ktor, kotlin-exposed

I am trying to insert some data into the database, and am getting the following error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `org.joda.time.DateTime` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2019-04-19')
```

My content negotiation

```
install(ContentNegotiation) {
        jackson {
            enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
        }
    }
```

And my model:

```
data class User(
//some codes
val registrationDate = DateTime  // org.joda.time.DateTime
)
```

And when will I send by json:

```
{
 //some other data
 "registrationDate" : "2019-07-15"
}
```

Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install the Joda module for Jackson https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda and add it to your jackson configuration in ktor :

```
install(ContentNegotiation) {
        jackson {
            registerModule(JodaModule())
            enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
        }
    }
```

You can also control serialization/deserialization behavior with annotations on your data class properties :

```
data class Account(
    val uid: String? = null,
    val firstName: String,
    val lastName: String,
    val email: String,
    @get:JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
    val createdTime: DateTime? = null
)
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot dude. It now records as timestamp, how do I record it as a date? yyyy-MM-dd?

Comment: Thank you again! =)